# Google cloud storage WAV file upload - “404 Requested Entity was not found”

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

My code references the one pasted here on google's website: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects

I am attempting to make a python program that records microphone mono audio, creates a WAV file out of it, and then uploads it GCS where it is then analyzed. The part where I am stuck at is the uploading to GC part. I don't know whats supposed to replace  as I don't even know how to find that file path. I do, however, know what the mybucket name is. It's "gcspeechstorage" (I made that). Also, the block of code that uploads a file to the bucket is very vague to me and I realize now that Google's boilerplate code is not working for me. I am getting a `"google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 requested entity was not found"` error.

If there is any way to get around this so I can upload a 1+ minute clip and have it analyzed that would be great. My NLTK works fine.

I defined the gcs_uri to equal `os.path.join('gs://<gcspeechstorage>/<file_path_inside_bucket>')` but I know that is only partially complete. I do not know how to complete that 2nd argument. I'm not even sure if the code is in the right order, to be honest.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import pprint
import argparse
import datetime
import io
import json
import os
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from google.cloud import storage
import sys
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 10
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/Project Mizu-7e2ecd8c5804.json'

bucket_name = "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/output.wav"
source_file_name = "gcspeechstorage"
destination_blob_name = "output.wav"
gcs_uri = "gs://gcspeechstorage/output.wav"

def create_bucket(bucket_name):
    """Creates a new bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
    print('Bucket {} created'.format(bucket.name))

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))

# [START speech_transcribe_async_gcs]
def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
    """Asynchronously transcribes the audio file specified by the gcs_uri."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding= 'LINEAR16',
        sample_rate_hertz=44100,
        language_code='en-US')

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
    response = operation.result(timeout=90)

    # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
    # them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
    for result in response.results:
        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
        print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))

        transcribedSpeechFile = open('speechToAnalyze.txt', 'a+')  # this is where a text file is made with the transcribed speech

        transcribedSpeechFile.write(format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))

        transcribedSpeechFile.close()

        print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))
# [END speech_transcribe_async_gcs]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri)


audio_rec = open('speechToAnalyze.txt', 'r')

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for sentence in audio_rec:
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
    for k in ss:
        print('{0}: {1}, '.format(k, ss[k]), end='')
    print()
```

Expected results: uploads WAV file to GCS, then retrieves it to transcribe, then analyzes the sentiment.

Actual results: records audio, then crashes giving me the aforementioned 404 error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 565, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 467, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.NOT_FOUND
    details = "Requested entity was not found."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1562714798.427000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[2607:f8b0:4000:804::200a]:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1052,"grpc_message":"Requested entity was not found.","grpc_status":5}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/FrankensteinedFile.py", line 100, in <module>
    transcribe_gcs('C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/output.wav')
  File "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/FrankensteinedFile.py", line 79, in transcribe_gcs
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\speech_v1\gapic\speech_client.py", line 326, in long_running_recognize
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 273, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 182, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Requested entity was not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, it looks like you're passing the gcs_uri `C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/output.wav` to your app, but that's a local file, not an object in GCS. You'll want to first upload the wav file to your GCS bucket, and then you'll want to cite that object when you call `long_running_recognize`. Try something more like this:

```
upload_blob("C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/output.wav", "gcspeechstorage", "output.wav")
transcribe_gcs("gs://gcspeechstorage/output.wav")
```

Comment: First of all - Thank you Brandon for taking time to help me with this. But I am running to some problems. When I tried to pass the arguments you mentioned into `upload-blob` and `transcribe_gcs` it returned an error (can't do that in Python). So what I did was assign the variables `bucket_name`, `source_file_name`, etc. to the values you mentioned I should assign them to. However this seems to cause a new error: `google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 No such object: gcspeechstorage/output.wav`. This doesn't make sense because I've created a bucket called gcspeechstorage. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try opening the Cloud Console UI and verifying that the file output.wav now exists in the bucket gcspeechstorage.

Comment: I checked the console and the bucket is empty ("there are no live objects"). I manually created the bucket yesterday.

Comment: I updated my code to show the changes I've made thus far.

Comment: Perhaps try simplifying by only doing one step. Manually upload a valid wav file to the bucket from the console. Then, try running only the transcribe step. That should work.

Comment: OK, so it successfully runs the program, transcribes the audio, but it only transcribes the file I manually uploaded. On subsequent test runs I cannot create a new audio file and upload it and then have Google transcribe it.

Comment: Okay, now try writing a small program that only uploads a file to GCS but doesn't do anything with it. It should look pretty much just like your `upload_blob` function. Verify that it worked by checking the console.

Comment: Okay so right now my create_bucket function and my upload_blob function are both non-functional. If I run the program, the compiler effectively ignores them both completely and just runs every other line of code instead (as evidenced by the fact that the program won't even display the print statements in either function in the output, not to mention the fact that no files ever get uploaded to the bucket). Do you have any advice on why this might be happening?

Comment: I don't. Try adding print statements, stepping through the program using pdb, or just putting the individual lines directly into an interpreter. Also, there's probably no need to worry about create_bucket. You created a bucket once. Just use that.